# Crashlitycs crash reports not always showing Firebase Analitycs data in logs

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, firebase-analytics, crashlytics-android

When forcing a crash in my app and looking at the reports in the Firebase console, for the same crash but in different sessions, sometimes the "Log" tab is filled with firebase Analitycs data (mostly screen_view), butmost of the times it is not. I am not changong anything in the code between all the sessions, and I can't figure out why sometimes Firebase Analitycs data isn't reported in the crash report.

In firebase DebugView, all the events are corectly reported.

I see the same behavior in my app in production. all crashes don't contain analitycs data.
I am not using opt-in crash report.

My gradle file contains up to date firebase-core and crashlitycs :

```
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
```

I am initializing Firebase with CrashLitycs, and Firebase Analitycs :

```
Fabric.with(context, new Crashlytics());
firebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
```

I expect to have all the analitycs related to a crash logged in the crash report.

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it could be an intended behavior based on where your crash is occurring. If that is crash occurs early in your app, then one possibility is that is that the crash happened immediately upon launch, before the screen_view event occurred or was captured.

The order of things that can happen on your phone is not deterministic, so even with the same issue, session logs can vary in this way.